# If I accept contributions under a CLA, can I write "Copyright (c) My-Name"?

Tags: open-source, licensing, contribution

I'm thinking about open sourcing a project of mine. I'd accept contributions under a [CLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contributor_License_Agreement) that grants me a copyright license (I'll explain what I mean at the  end of this question). — Now, if someone submits a contribution, is it then okay that I write `Copyright (c) 2013 My-Name` at the top of each file? And mention any contributors in a separate document only, and refer people to the Git commit log and to GitHub statistics if they want details on individual contributors?

I think this should be fine with `Copyright (c) My-Name`, since I've been granted a copyright license?

If it's not okay, then I suppose the copyright-info-preamble of each source code file would have to include the name of all contributors to that file? Which doesn't seem practical (if there are very many contributors).

---

Here I'll try to explain what I mean with a *"a CLA that grants me a copyright license"*. This is an edited excerpt from a CLA by [Google](https://developers.google.com/open-source/cla/individual):

> .2. [...] You [*that is, the contributor*] hereby grant to [*My-Name, that is, me*] and to recipients of software
>   distributed by [*My-Name*] a perpetual, worldwide, non-exclusive,
>   no-charge, royalty-free, irrevocable copyright license to reproduce,
>   prepare derivative works of, publicly display, publicly perform,
>   sublicense, and distribute Your Contributions and such derivative
>   works.

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but that only grants you license and the license is non-exclusive. So the original author should be named.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you may not.

"Copyright (C) (year) (name): All Rights Reserved" is a *copyright notice*.  A copyright notice states unequivocally that YOU own the work in question, and people desiring to use the work must deal with you.  Note that the phrasing is High Magic: it **must** be phrased precisely this way.

Google's *Contributor License Agreement* (CLA) means that the person who owns the work in question has granted Google a license to use it, in accordance with the terms of the license.  **It does not transfer ownership of the work**.  The owner retains his rights as owner, unless he specifically gives them up (translation: SELLS them, in most cases).  This specifically includes the right to license the work to other people, regardless of how Google might feel about those other people.

Affixing a copyright notice to a work for which you have been assigned a license, but have not actually acquired ownership, is misrepresentation.

Comment: True, although there are lots of Free/Open Source Software projects that insist on transfer of copyright for free.  That includes the FSF itself, for GCC and other major programs.

Comment: Copyright notices are not "High Magic"; in fact they're not even required anymore. See Berne Convention, WIPO Copyright Treaty and WTO TRIPS. However, if you _do_ use them, you indeed should use them correctly.

Comment: @MSalters, there is a world of difference between what is in theory required by those conventions and what is in fact necessary if you plan to pursue a copyright infringement action, in US courts at least.

Comment: What about writing `Copyright (c) Original-Author's-Name and contributors`? (That is, including "and contributors".) At least some files in WordPress does this, e.g. [this](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/SimplePie/Registry.php) and fairly many actually, if you [google for `copyright * "and contributors"`](https://www.google.se/search?q=copyright+*+%22and+contributors%22)

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: What's required in US courts is registration, which may done ex post facto.

Comment: @MSalters: When fighting a copyright case in court, one of three things can happen.  1) Nobody brings a registration certificate: CASE DISMISSED!  2) One party brings a certificate: HE WINS! (unless the other party fights one HELL of an uphill battle to rebut the presumption that the certificate is valid.)  3) Both  parties bring certificates: EARLIEST DATE STAMP WINS!  So you register EARLY, before you need to.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: You might be confusing it with patents, where it is reasonable for two people to come up with the same idea. In these cases, a fraudulent registration (claiming ownership, regardless of date stamp) is not evidence. 17 USC 411.